# Meteor: Creating URLs for sharing (currently using iron-router)

Tags: javascript, url, meteor, iron-router

I have a meteor app that uses iron-router.

How do I make this meteor app create a fixed URL for sharing?

For example in jsfiddle.net, you start of in just `jsfiddle.net` PLAINLY.

However, after you type in the code, etc...and you decide you wanna share this with the world, you click on save.  After you click on save, the link above changes to something like: `jsfiddle.net/m9mfLn3p/`.
And now you can use `jsfiddle.net/m9mfLn3p/` to share that page with that certain setting with the world....

How do I achieve something similar in my meteor app that uses iron-router?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I see there's a far more intricate answer, but if all you mean is share a single URL for a Meteor app, you simply need to go beyond running it locally (on localhost:3000 by default), and deploy it via "meteor deploy <appName>" After that, you can share <appName>.meteor.com I think it is.

Comment: That's not what I meant...the answer below is much closer to the point...Thank you for sharing though

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar pattern in my app. To solve this problem I have a collection that contains the data context that will be used by the route. Then I just create a document with the required data and use the `_id` of the document in that collection to create a url that can be reused.

Ex:

```
var id = Permalinks.insert(object); // object is the data I'll need later
var url = Meteor.absoluteUrl() + "myPath/" + id;
... share this url however - email, SMS, etc...
```

Then a route:

```
Router.route("/myPath/:id",{
  data: function(){
    return Permalinks.findOne({ _id: this.params.id });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks..I'll try that...but about using _id....is that considered acceptable/good practice? or is it a security risk to expose the actual id of the object?

Comment: Object ids are generally available in the client, it's not a security risk per se unless its an id of an object the user shouldn't have access to anyway.

Comment: You could expose a token that's derived from the id but ultimately it would have to map back to the id anyway so that would only be veneer.

Comment: Do you think it is a good idea to make the document the permalinks depend on undeletable, thus making it permanent?  This way when they share the permalink there won't be a risk of having a path not found error in the future if they delete it intentionally or unintentionally.  What do u think? or is it normal to provide the user an option of deleting what they shared via the permalink?  What are your thoughts on this?  Thank you..

Comment: If it's really a permalink, then yes, make it undeletable. If it's something transient - like an *invitation to join* for example, then there's no problem with it going away later but you'll then want to handle that with something nicer than a 404.